# Which one is equivalent Code A in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

There are Code A、Code B and Code C.

1. Is Code A equivalent Code B ?
2. Is Code A equivalent Code C ?

**Code A**

```
 if (IsRegistered(myContext) ) {

 }
```

**Code B**

```
if (IsRegistered(myContext) == true) {

}
```

**Code C**

```
if (IsRegistered(myContext) === true) {

}
```

**Function**

```
fun IsRegistered(myContext: Context): Boolean {
    val prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(myContext)

    var registeredStatus: Boolean? = prefs.getBoolean("IsRegistered", false)

    val isPro = myContext.resources.getBoolean(R.bool.IsProVersion)
    if (isPro) {
        registeredStatus = true
    }

    return registeredStatus!!    
}
```

Comment: code A code B and code C are the same  in kotlin

Comment: You are _probably_ getting a compiler warning to not compare primitives with `===`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code A and B are totally identical. The first one isn preferable since the equality check in B is just noisy. Code C, on the other hand, checks for [*referential equality*](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/equality.html#referential-equality):

> Referential equality is checked by the `===` operation (and its negated counterpart `!==`). `a === b` evaluates to `true` if and only if a and b point to the same object. For **values which are represented as primitive types** at runtime (for example, Int), the `===` equality check is **equivalent** to the `==` check.

If you use your Code C though, the IDE (at least IDEA) does not like it and tells you that it's "deprecated" to use `===` on the `Boolean` type.
It has been discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45222144/identity-equality-for-arguments-of-types-int-and-int-is-deprecated?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Code B should be recommended here.

Answer (score -1):

Code A is equivalent Code B since

> a === b evaluates to true if and only if a and b point to the same
>   object.

Answer (score -1):

```
 if (IsRegistered(myContext) ) {

 }
```

Code in if will be executed if method IsRegistered returns true.

```
if (IsRegistered(myContext) == true) {

}
```

This will be executed if methods returns true. Actually it unnecessary comparison, but can be useful if IsRegistered may return null (because null isn't true), but in this case, its just additional 8 chars.

```
if (IsRegistered(myContext) === true) {

}
```

This is also equivalent to A and B, because Boolean is an primitive type, and === operator is the same as == (ref: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/equality.html#referential-equality)